# How to display leaf node story count on a board

Tags: rally

I' m struggling to display leaf node count on individual cards of a feature story board. I' m using Lookback API to query leaf node stories. Below code is not displaying data correctly and its skipping the field for an entire column. Could you please let me know what I 'm doing wrong here or if there's an easy way to do this. I 'm a novice app developer. Thanks in advance!

```
cardConfig: {
editable: false,
showIconsAndHighlightBorder: false,
fields: [
    'Name', 
    {
        name: 'LeafCount', //field name
        hasValue: function() {return true;}, //always show this field
        renderTpl: Ext.create('Rally.ui.renderer.template.LabeledFieldTemplate', {
                    fieldLabel: 'Leaf story Count', //the field label
                    valueTemplate: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate', 
                        ['{[this.getLeafCount(values)]}',
                         {getLeafCount: function(data) {
                            var OID = data.ObjectID;
                            snapshotStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.lookback.SnapshotStore', {
                                listeners: {
                                    load: function(store, records, success) {
                                        console.log(records.length);
                                        count = records.length;
                                    }
                                }, 
                                autoLoad: true,
                                useHttpPost: true,
                                fetch: ['Name', 'FormattedID', 'ObjectID'],
                                find: {
                                    "_ItemHierarchy": OID,
                                    "_TypeHierarchy": "HierarchicalRequirement",
                                    "Children": null,
                                    "__At": "current"
                                },
                                scope: this
                            });
                            return count;
                        //    return snapshotStore.totalCount;
                            }
                         }])
                })
    },
    //additional string fields
    'c_StoryType', 'Project', 'PlanEstimate', 'Parent', 'TaskEstimateTotal', 'TaskRemainingTotal']
```

},

Answer (score 0):

This isn't working for you because all the data needs to be available when the template is evaluated- there isn't time to do an async store load before rendering the value.

For this specific case can't you just show the built-in LeafStoryCount field on your cards?

Comment: I 'm not aware of built-in LeafStoryCount field. I couldn't find it in the documentation. Could you please point me to an example.

Comment: It's on the root PortfolioItem type that each of the PI types (feature, initiative, etc.) extend from.

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/objectModel.sp#attr-41106

Comment: Thanks! But we don't have PI subscription.

Comment: oh, so you're just using epic stories then.  i see.  this is a much more difficult problem then.  probably the best way forward is to create a custom card and then load the data for each card and then add a field to the card once the data is there.  i'll try to whip up a better example of this soon...

Comment: Yes I' m using epic stories. An example would be great. Thank you very much Kyle!

Comment: Hi Kyle, Sorry to bother you. Did you get a chance to work on the example?

Comment: Sorry, not quite yet.  It's on my list!